# Loop through directory and zip specific folder without parent path

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm trying to make a bash script to loop through all folder in directories, and individually zip just the folder I want without all path and choose where to zip theme.

```
#!/bin/bash

for dir in /MyPersonalFolder/*/*/WhatIWantFolder
do   
   folder_number=$(basename ${dir%/*}) ### basename get the name of this folder [*] 'folder have numbers' /MyPersonalFolder/*/[*]/WhatIWantFolder
   sudo tar -cf "${folder_number}-WhatIWantFolder".tar.gz --absolute-names "$dir"   
   mkdir -p ./backup-theme/ && sudo mv "${folder_number}-theme".tar.gz $_ ### I use this to move zipped folder to specific directory if i can choose where to zip file in the zip command line it's better
done
```

I can zip the folder I want, but the output zip file comes with this content:

```
/MyPersonalFolder/0001/0001/WhatIWantFolder
```

But what I need is to output the file with this path:

```
0001/
  |___WhatIWantFolder/
```

I tried to change "$dir" in this line

```
sudo tar -cf "${folder_number}-WhatIWantFolder".tar.gz --absolute-names "$dir"
```

with basename ${dir%/*}

```
sudo tar -cf "${folder_number}-WhatIWantFolder".tar.gz --absolute-names "basename ${dir%/*}"
```

tar not found the folder it's come with errors

```
tar: e0001: Cannot stat: No such file or directory
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can cd to another directory while running `tar` using the `--cd` option.

```sh
#!/bin/bash

for dir in MyPersonalFolder/*/*/WhatIWantFolder; do
    parent="${dir%/*/*}"
    subdir="${dir#*/*/*}"
    outfile="backup-theme/${subdir/\//-}.tar.gz"

    tar --cd "$parent" -cvzf "$outfile" "$subdir" 
done
```

The directory structure of the tar file would look something like this:

```
tar -tf backup-theme/0001-WhatIWantFolder.tar.gz
0001/WhatIWantFolder/
0001/WhatIWantFolder/f1
```

Comment: Thank you it's work : --cd doesn't work for me, I change it with --directory,

Comment: I'm glad it worked. I'm using bsdtar 3.3.2 which also supports `--directory` and `-C`. This is the first time I've seen the option as `--cd`.